# Problem with strings in assembler [beginner]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, char, intel, assembly

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and here's a little bit of code I'm having trouble with:

```
void main()
{
int x;
char c1[100]="cd";
char c2[100]="abcdef";
_asm {
    lea edx,c2
    lea ecx,c1
    push edx
    push ecx
    call subsir
    add esp, 8   
    mov x, eax
}
}

char subsir (char *c1, char *c2) 
{
_asm {
mov ecx, c1
mov edx, c2
mov edi, 0
mov esi, 0
start: cmp [edx + edi], 0
je end
mov esi, 0
mov eax, [edx + edi]
cmp eax, [ecx + esi]
  .....
```

This is the first part of a program that's meant to compare 2 words.

The problem I am having is that when I do

```
 mov eax, [edx + edi]
```

eax receives an adress and not the actual value.
I tested this by doing

```
 cmp eax, 97
```

which should activate a JE instruction (97 being the ASCII code for 'a') But it doesn't. If I do

```
      cmp [edx + edi], 97
```

it does activate the JE jump.

I would be very grateful if you could tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I put the actual valuea in EAX instead of an adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is actually reading the memory at [edx + edi].  Problem is that it is reading 32-bits at a time.  Which is not okay, you are comparing string content.  That requires comparing one byte at a time.  Fix:

```
start: cmp byte ptr [edx + edi], 0
je end
mov esi, 0
mov al, [edx + edi]
cmp al, [ecx + esi]
```